# Backwards compatible PHP SOAP interface

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, backwards-compatibility

I've got a PHP webapplication that's connected with another application using SOAP. In order to maintain the connection when updated my application, the interface needs to be one version backwards compatible. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this, eg:

- Creating a different input for each version (disadvantage: requires more maintenance)
- Creating a layer upon the (only) input that converts the XML to the new version (advantage: one way of process)

Comment: With SOAP you normally have one endpoint per each version. The client application then can decide which one to use. In your scenario you would maintain two versions of the SOAP API all the time. The last one and the current one.

Comment: The only challenge is that both versions using the same database. So how to handle complex changes that have been made in the new version.

Comment: Well whatever changes behind must not play a role for the interface to access it. You're probably looking for the facade or adapter pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I tend to deploy multiple versions of an app in this kind of situation:

- /api/0.1/ <- branch 0.1 deployed here
- /api/0.2/ <- branch 0.2 deployed here
- etc.

Answering the comment: no particular reasons. When I began to do this, it was for convenience: I'd svn checkout/update all svn branches in one location, instead of doing an svn checkout of each branch in independent folders. It then stuck over the years even as I switched to git and other ways to deploy.

I suppose one benefit over an `/api/{version}/` setup with files deployed in `/api/` is that you never risk a regression in the older versions of your APIs when you update dependencies or refactor code.

Comment: Can you argument why not to use the layer upon the current version?